Get Client Id on_message in Subscriber
in subscriber, I want to know the client id of the publisher.
but not working..
def on_message(mqttc, obj, msg):
    _logger.info(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.qos) + " " + str(msg.payload) +" from "+str(mqttc._client_id))


MQTT broker ( mosquitto )
Client ( paho python )

Here is my test.
I used client id = "v60,v5.1,0035" and publish.
but in subscriber, client id was empty.
Publisher example
(mypy) taroumaru@ubuntu:~/python/paho.mqtt.python/examples
$ python3 client_pub_opts.py -t group/topic1 -c "v60,v5.1,0035"
2024-08-25 13:01:38,181 __main__:131 <module> [INFO]: Connecting to localhost port: 1883
2024-08-25 13:01:38,187 __main__:139 <module> [INFO]: Publishing: {"msgnum": "0"}
2024-08-25 13:01:38,188 __main__:70 on_connect [INFO]: connect reason_code: Success
2024-08-25 13:01:38,189 __main__:78 on_publish [INFO]: mid: 1 from b'v60,v5.1,0035'

Subscriber example
(mypy) taroumaru@ubuntu:~/python/paho.mqtt.python/examples
$ python3 client_sub_opts.py -t group/topic1
2024-08-25 13:01:34,690 __main__:135 <module> [INFO]: Connecting to localhost port: 1883
2024-08-25 13:01:34,701 __main__:69 on_connect [INFO]: reason_code: Success
2024-08-25 13:01:34,701 __main__:81 on_subscribe [INFO]: Subscribed: 1 [ReasonCode(Suback, 'Granted QoS 0')]
2024-08-25 13:01:38,189 __main__:73 on_message [INFO]: group/topic1 0 b'{"msgnum": "0"}' from b''


Hello all    I resolve this issue in here !      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593770/mqtt-subscriber-to-know-who-is-the-publisher

With MQTTv5 you can add the information to a MQTT header property

The mqttc object in the callback is the local client, not the remote client.
